# Prove that the set of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices is a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let H be the set of all symmetric $n\times n$ matrices:

$H = \{A ∈ M_{n\times n}(R) | A^T = A\}$.

Prove that H is a subspace of $M_{n\times n}(R)$.

Comment: Do you know the vector space or subspace axioms?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2063327/29335) is even a more general duplicate, but the one I linked is more useful.  Please search for your question before posting it, in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to show: if $A,B \in H$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, then

$A+B \in H$ amd $ \alpha A \in H$.

Comment: Oh yeah... right