# Prove symmetric matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

(a)Prove sum and difference of two symmetric matrices are also symmetric.

(b)Prove $A^n$ is a symmetric matrix if $A$ is a symmetric matrix

For (a), let matrices $A$ and $B$ be two symmetric matrices such that $A=A^T$ and $B=B^T$

$$A+B=A^T+B^T=(A+B)^T$$
$$A+B=(A+B)^T$$

Therefore, sum of two symmetric matrices are also symmetric

Similarly, $$A-B=A^T-B^T=(A-B)^T$$
$$A-B=(A-B)^T$$

Therefore, the difference of two symmetric matrices are also symmetric

For(b), if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, $$A=A^T$$ $$A^n=(A^T)^n$$

Note that by properties of the transpose of the matrix, $$(AB)^T=B^TA^T$$ thus $$A^n=AA...A$$ $$(A^n)^T=A^TA^T...A^T$$ $$(A^n)^T=(A^T)^n$$

Therefore, $$A=A^T$$ $$A^n=(A^T)^n$$ $$A^n=(A^n)^T$$

Do I make any mistake(s)?

Comment: I do not understand how you go from $A^T+B^T = (A+B)^T$.  I would expand upon this or cite an earlier proved result.  Try approaching using the definitions of transposition and addition of matrices.

Comment: It's correct. ${{{}}}$

Comment: $(a)$ follows, since symmetric matrices of size $n$ form a subspace of $M_n(K)$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063327/prove-that-symmetric-matrices-of-order-n-form-the-subspace-of-m-n-bbb-f-di).